# error due to separating values in string by comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

in the below code i am trying to split values by comma. despite the values i pass in the url are comma separated, however i get the
below posted error

please tell me how to fix this error

**url with comma separated values**:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/11.11,22.22,33.33,44.44
```

**output**:

```
11.11,22.22,33.33,44.44
['11.11', '22.22', '33.33', '44.44']
11.11
22.22
33.33
44.44
api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car?api_key=5b3ce359785131d001cf62480ecf8c403567479a87de01dffunrda651fb&start=11.11,22.22&end=33.33,44.44
https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car?api_key=5b3ce359785131d001cf62480ecf8c403567479a87de01dffunrda651fb&start=11.11,22.22&end=33.33,44.44
```

**code**:

```
@app.route("/<string:startAndEndCoord>", methods=['GET'] )
def startCoord(startAndEndCoord):
    #api_key = request.args.get('api_key')
    # startLat, startLng= request.args.get('start').split(',')
    # end1Lat, endLng = request.args.get('end').split(',')
    
    print(startAndEndCoord)
    print(startAndEndCoord.split(','))
    
    startLat, startLng, end1Lat, endLng = startAndEndCoord.split(',')
    print(startLat)
    print(startLng)
    print(end1Lat)
    print(endLng)
    
    print(config['EndPoint']['url'] +  config['EndPoint']['api_key'] + "&start=" + startLat + "," + startLng + "&end=" + end1Lat + "," + endLng)
    baseURL = "https://" + config['EndPoint']['url'] +  config['EndPoint']['api_key'] + "&start=" + startLat + "," + startLng + "&end=" + end1Lat + "," + endLng
    print(baseURL)
    
    # urllib.request.urlopen(baseURL)
    return config['EndPoint']['url'] + config['EndPoint']['api_key'] + "&start=" + startLat + "," + startLng + "&end=" + end1Lat + "," + endLng 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(DEBUG=True)
```

**error**:

```
1.py", line 39, in startCoord
startLat, startLng, end1Lat, endLng = startAndEndCoord.split(',')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

Comment: with this line `startLat, startLng, end1Lat, endLng = startAndEndCoord.split(',')`, it is expected that `split()` returns four elements which is failing for some input where it only returns a single value: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)`

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia would you please tell me how to overcome such problem...the input in the url contains always four values

Comment: try to store the four values in a variable and then try to unpack it.

Comment: so like

```val = startAndEndCoord.split(',')``` and then

```startLat, startLng, end1Lat, endLng = val
```